# how do you add more variables to an if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am new to coding. I would like to add more variables to my current code. Right now if you type in "dog" it will open youtube. How would you add another variable so that if you typed dog it would still open youtube but if you typed "cat" it would open Netflix for example? How do you do this?
thank you to any and all who help. just remember I am still new to coding so please do not criticize.

```
   const myFunction = () => {
  if (document.getElementById('textInput').value === 'dog'){
    window.open( 
              "https://youtube.com", "_blank"); 
  }
}
<input type="text" id="textInput" oninput="myFunction()">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
you can add a else statement checking for dog and window.open netflix

Comment: [Add `else` branches to the `if` statement.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) Really, this isn't the place for your question. Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site. Check the language documentation (as I've provided) or use Google for questions like this.

Comment: I'd go for a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score -1):

Here it is :

```
const myFunction = () => {

if (document.getElementById('textInput').value === 'dog'){

 window.open(  "https://youtube.com", "_blank"); 

 } else if (document.getElementById('textInput').value === 'cat'){

 window.open(  "https://netflix.com", "_blank");
 }
}
<input type="text" id="textInput" oninput="myFunction()">
```

Comment: This is not a question that should be posted on Stack Overflow in the first place as the comments that were present before you posted your answer state. We tend not to answer these questions because it just attracts more of the same, which we don't want here.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is probably `else if`. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#using_else_if), explained better than I could explain it for you.
Also, if you want to call the same element more than once, you can save it as a variable similarly to the snippet attached below.

If you want the different words to run the same code, or (`||`) and and(`&&`) logical operators are what you need instead. E.x. `if(inputElem === 'dog' || inputElem === 'cat')`

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  var inputElem = document.getElementById('textInput');
  if (inputElem.value === 'dog'){
    console.log('the value was dog');
  } else if(inputElem.value == 'cat') {
    console.log('the value was cat');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textInput" oninput="myFunction()">
```

Comment: This is not a question that should be posted on Stack Overflow in the first place as the comments that were present before you posted your answer state. We tend not to answer these questions because it just attracts more of the same, which we don't want here.

Answer (score -1):

u can use switch case to handle your solution

```
switch(document.getElementById('textInput').value) {
   case 'dog':
       window.open( 
          "https://youtube.com", "_blank"); 
   break;
   case 'cat':
      window.open( 
          "https://google.com", "_blank"); 
   break;
   default:
     // When you write a word that you did not consider (in this example, except for dogs and cats, enter this block)
   break;
 }
```

Comment: This is not a question that should be posted on Stack Overflow in the first place as the comments that were present before you posted your answer state. We tend not to answer these questions because it just attracts more of the same, which we don't want here.